# Document.write(<script>) throws Unexpected token "ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, html-entities, html-escape-characters

Before you ask, I already searched a lot in Stack Overflow and I google it thousand times. Any other case I ever seen here helped me.

**Let's go to my problem:**

I'm trying to use the following script in my code:

```
<script type='text/javaScript'>
    document.write("<script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/"+hom_cat1+"?max-results=1&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showhomeposts1'></script>");
</script>
```

But I'm using Blogger and it don't detect correctly my code (note the red script closing tag):

[image: note the red script closing tag]

With this, I can't save the Template. So I'm trying to use convert my code into HTML entities using this [website](http://htmlentities.net/). When I encode, put this into my template and save, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Here's the encoded string I'm trying to use:

```
&lt;script type='text/javaScript'&gt;document.write(&quot;&lt;script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot;+hom_cat1+&quot;?max-results=1&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showhomeposts1'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

### What can I do to solve my issue?

Comment: Just wondering, why not just insert script tag into document with appropriate `src`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that the string passed to `document.write` includes the characters `</script>`, which ends up prematurely terminating the script element that `document.write` is called from.

The characters `</script>` can't appear anywhere within a script, since the HTML parser has no way to distinguish this from an actual `</script>` tag.

You could try something like this instead:

```
document.write("<script src='...'></scr" + "ipt>");
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments:

```
document.write("<script src='...'><\/script>");
```

Another option is to use the DOM API to create a `script` element and insert it into the document. The other answers here give some suggestions for that, but there are potential problems with the implementations (for example, `document.body.appendChild` will throw a TypeError if you try to call it from within the `head`). Something like this would be more robust:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://something.com';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}());
```

Also, `type='text/javaScript'` is incorrect; use `text/javascript` or omit the `type` attribute.

Comment: I typically recommend using `<\/script>` in the string, as it avoids the need for string concatenation, however it's easy to overlook.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I used to do it like that too, but `\/` isn't a "real" escape, it's just something that happens to work (as far as I can tell from looking at ES5 section 7.8.4, no behavior is defined for backslash followed by something that isn't an escape character or part of an escape sequence).

Comment: @DaggNabbit "The CV of *CharacterEscapeSequence* :: *NonEscapeCharacter* is the CV of the *NonEscapeCharacter*.", isn't that the case?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, you're right, I guess I didn't read down far enough. So the behavior is defined in ES5. I wonder if it was defined in ES3, because at some point I decided `\/` was no good, and now I wonder why (also now that I'm reading it again, I see that it says "
CharacterEscapeSequence ::
SingleEscapeCharacter
NonEscapeCharacter" earlier on).

Comment: Nope, it's in ES3 too. Maybe `\/` is the way to go.

Comment: I've also thought at some point it was not good mainly because it looks like a typo which the next developer may remove and then the system is broken (though, I believe all alternatives would look a bit "wrong" but it would not be hard to hit Ctrl+Z after it causes such an evident issue). Anyway, I just wanted to make sure the behavior was defined because H5BP still uses `\/` which made me curious. `=]`

Answer (score 4):

You are writing

```
<script type='text/javaScript'>
    document.write("<script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/"+hom_cat1+"?max-results=1&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showhomeposts1'></script>");
</script>
```

So output will be script tag inside script tag that's why your output will be

```
&lt;script type='text/javaScript'&gt;document.write(&quot;&lt;script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot;+hom_cat1+&quot;?max-results=1&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showhomeposts1'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

Instead that use only  document.write("");

***or***

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

Comment: nice solutions. especially the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Better way to load js asynch is like this

```
function loadScript () {

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'feeds/posts/default/your.js' 
    document.body.appendChild(script);

}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

or if you don't want any function, you can use direct invocation

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'feeds/posts/default/your.js' 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

As suggested by google also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#asynch

Answer (score 0):

if you on Django , and have somewhere similar problem: try this:

```
<script src="{% static 'my/path/to/script.js' %}" ></script>
```